# Firebase unlink email/password auth from user on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to unlink email/password authentication from a user in Swift on iOS. I've read [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking) and managed to link and unlink Facebook authentication without a problem. However, after linking email/password credentials successfully, the `providerData` object is nil. The `providerID` is "Firebase" but when I pass that to the unlink code the following error is thrown:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17016 "User was not linked to an account with the given provider." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=User was not linked to an account with the given provider., error_name=ERROR_NO_SUCH_PROVIDER}
```

The unlink code I'm using is:

```
let providerId = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.providerID)!
print("Trying to unlink:",providerId)     // providerId = "Firebase"
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.unlinkFromProvider(providerId) { user, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Unlink error:", error)
    } else {
        // Provider unlinked from account successfully
       print("Unlinked...user.uid:", user!.uid, "Anonymous?:", user!.anonymous)
        }
    }
```

Reading the docs and having got it working for Facebook, I expected the providerData array to be populated with something after email authentication. So is my linking code wrong (it doesn't throw an error and appears to work fine)?

**My linking code**:

```
let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credentialWithEmail(email, password: password)

FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.linkWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
    if user != nil && error == nil {
        // Success
        self.success?(user: user!)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            if type == "new" {
                print("New user logged in...")
            }
            if type == "existing" {
                print("Existing user logged in...")
            }
        })
    } else {
        print("Login error:",error)
        self.showOKAlertWithTitle("Login Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Any pointers of how I can modify my approach would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To get the profile information retrieved from the sign-in providers linked to a user, use the [providerData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) property.

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
  for profile in user.providerData {
    // Id of the provider (ex: facebook.com)
    let providerID = profile.providerID
  }
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

Calling FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.providerID will result to "firebase".